# Requisição CUrl não funciona dependendo do tamanho do JSON

Tags: php, json, libcurl

Meu problema é que dependendo do tamanho do `JSON` enviado, a requisição `CUrl` não funciona, ou seja caso eu envie 2 fotos no `JSON`, da certo, mas 4 já é motivo para um `TimeOut`.

O problema não está na `API` pois no `Postman` funciona independentemente do tamanho do `JSON`, ou seja, creio que seja alguma configuração que eu não esteja setando, alguém tem alguma ideia?

**Estrutura do CUrl...**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => trim($this->vg['url'] . $url1 . $url2),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              "Cache-control: no-cache",
              "Accept: application/json",
              "Content-type: application/json",
            ),
          ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O timeout do cURL está em 30s, troque a linha abaixo:

```
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30
```

para (1800 = 30min):

```
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1800
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php

Coloca também o código abaixo antes de tudo. Note: 30*60 = 1800s = 30min máximo de timeout (tempo de execução máxima). E o post_max_size tb tem influência no upload de arquivos, segundo a documentação do php.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30*60);
ini_set('post_max_size','256M');
```

Fonte: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php

Comment: já tinha tentado isso não resolveu

Comment: Seu servidor está habilitado para vc reconfigurar em execução pelo php? Qual o erro exibido?

Comment: Cara... o timeout do cURL está em 30segundos (CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30), já tentou aumentar ele também para CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1800?

Comment: Sim kkk, aumentei ao máximo, simplesmente fica em um looping infinito, basta eu aumentar um pouco o json e já era

Comment: Estranho... já usei o cURL do php para enviar até 4GB e deu certo.